# Connecting my connectionstring to my Entity Framework MVC4 program

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having some trouble with connecting my connectionstring to my Entity Framework MVC4 program.

Here is my connectionstring:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="testContext" 
     connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=C:\folders\SQL\SQL\App_Data\TEST1.mdf;"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Here is my error code:

```
An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Directory lookup for the file "C:\folders\SQL\SQL\App_Data\TEST1.mdf" failed with the operating system error 5(Access is denied.).

CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.
```

Comment: and with "inegrated security = None", is it working?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you the user that the app is running as doesn't have access to the c:\folders.... directory.

Another problem (once the first is resolved) is that you are missing the "Database" parameter in the connection string.

```
connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=C:\folders\SQL\SQL\App_Data\TEST1.mdf;Database=dbnamehere;"
```